# How to properly use setSeed() method in SecureRandom to generate RSA primes

Tags: java, random, cryptography, rsa

I want to produce the two prime numbers for RSA key generation. I think in order to increase both primes' randomness, the random may be generated as the following:

```
SecureRandom r = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
r.setSeed(1232);
p = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, r);
q = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, r);
```

My question is: Do you think using `SecureRandom` will increase the `p` and `q` randomness? If so, how can I randomly set the value of `setSeed()` instead of making it a fixed value ( here i chose 1232)?

Comment: I would simply never call `setSeed`. `SecureRandom` automatically seeds itself when you don't call `setSeed`.

Comment: Your solution is already optimal. Seed is appended to the automatically generated one (if used at all). None of the "do this, do that" answers I really get.

Answer (score 3):

As CodesInChaos already shows, the default implementation of the SUN provider automatically seeds itself using the system random number generator. As Java itself doesn't have an (explicit) entropy source it is more or less dependent on the system for its seed.

You should never call `setSeed` before retrieving data from the `"SHA1PRNG"` in the SUN provider as that will make your RNG (Random Number Generator) into a Deterministic RNG - it will *only* use the given seed instead of adding the seed to the state. In other words, it will always generate the same stream of pseudo random bits or values.

The initial call to `setSeed` may differ per provider. Sometimes it will use the seed as only seed, but it may also just add the seed to the current state. On later Android versions (4.2 onwards) the seed is just added to the random state, so the `"SHA1RNG"` will stay fully random.

Probably the best way to generate your random number generator is just

```
SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
```

and let the Java runtime figure out the best one.

---

If you want to use an explicit algorithm (which is, however, ill-described by SUN/Oracle) then you could use:

```
SecureRandom r = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
```

as in your code.

Nowadays, it is also possible to use the NIST algorithms using `"DRBG"` as algorithm description, which you can then configure for the VM using the security properties.

Neither `"SHA1PRNG"` nor `"DRBG"` are implementation requirements, and it may differ per runtime / provider which algorithm is used or how they are seeded. I would never use them to re-generate a stream of previously generated bytes or values; please use a stream cipher for that. For instance, you could use a cipher instance `Cipher` for `"AES/CTR/NoPadding"` and encrypt zero-valued bytes to get to the key stream.

---

If you want to **add** entropy, use:

```
// just used to make sure that the SecureRandom is seeded by the OS
r.nextBytes(new byte[8]);
r.setSeed(1232);
```

A constant value or literal doesn't contain much (if any) entropy. Usual sources of entropy are the current time (or even better, `System.nanoTime()`), mouse movements etc.

---

For Java 8 there is a new method [`getInstanceStrong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstanceStrong--) with the following description:

> Returns a SecureRandom object that was selected by using the algorithms/providers specified in the securerandom.strongAlgorithms Security property.
>
> Some situations require strong random values, such as when creating high-value/long-lived secrets like RSA public/private keys. To help guide applications in selecting a suitable strong SecureRandom implementation, Java distributions include a list of known strong SecureRandom implementations in the `securerandom.strongAlgorithms` Security property.

Which should be used as a replacement for the call to the constructor. Be warned that this may return a *blocking* RNG, that is: an RNG that may block your thread until sufficient entropy has become available. It may also drain your OS entropy pool blocking *other* applications, so only use it sparingly.

Comment: Hey Mike, it seems you've never accepted this answer; is there anything missing from it?